# Как правильно произнести числительные?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, числительные, даты

*В 1580–1581 годах.*

Как правильно произнести?

Comment: @shampar Было вроде 1581?

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Да пусть будет как прежде, просто «между первой и второй» промежутка-то не бывает, как известно. Тот самый случай: интервала нет, а тире стоит. Не только здесь недочёт, — наращение добавил бы, которое способствует верному произнесению: «В 1580 и 1581-м годах».

Comment: @shampar Согласен, теперь считаю, что нельзя оформлять как диапазон.

Comment: @shampar Наращение со словом "год" не используется.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Запрета нет. Если помогает, то почему бы не нарастить.

Answer (score 3):

Тысяча пятьсот восьмидесятый, тысяча пятьсот восемьдесят первый — это порядковые числительные.
В составных порядковых числительных форму порядкового числительного имеет только последнее слово. При склонении таких числительных изменяется только последнее слово.

При склонении сложного порядкового числительного первая его часть всегда имеет форму родительного падежа (кроме числительных *сорок, девяносто, сто*); вторая часть имеет окончание, которое зависит от формы порядкового числительного  (рода, числа и падежа).
Получаем концовку: в восьмидесятом (году), в первом (году).

Произносим: в тысяча пятьсот восьмидесятом [пауза] тысяча пятьсот восемьдесят первом годах.
Или так: в тысяча пятьсот восьмидесятом [пауза] восемьдесят первом годах.

[Порядковые числительные](https://izamorfix.ru/rus/morfologiya/poryadkovye_chislit.html)

Comment: А тире правильное? Вроде бы короткое ставится.

Comment: Конечно, короткое. "Щаз" поправим. Хотя считается, что можно и обычное, лишь бы не дефис.

Comment: Не знаю, длинное выглядит неудачно, даже неуместно. Хм, а это похоже на дефис.

Comment: Ну не знаю... Вот, сравнивайте: — (тире); – (короткое тире); - (дефис).

Comment: Ещё от шрифта зависит. В этом короткое и дефис какие-то мелкие.

Comment: Интересно, что в мобильных версиях длинное тире (—) выглядит нормально, а вот на компьютере оно прям ну о-очень длинное, несуразное, на мой взгляд. Поэтому я предпочитаю использовать короткое (–).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Согласен, длинновато, но уже привык. А короткое там подлинее (как надо).